# How to customize django admin dashboard page

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new in django framework. I want to customize django admin panel. I want to create a page after login which has a menu to left panel and some details to the right panel, how can I create this type of page.

Answer (score 0):

Generally - one should not use the admin interface for your production purposes. The "admin" should be reserved for deployers/owners of your business "applications" and for the developers of the system.   If you want to create a separate page which is used by your end users, avoid using the admin side.

If you are looking for just changes in look and feel - maybe you should explore packages from  - https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/admin-styling/. If something paid stuff - explore http://djangosuit.com

Enjoy!